# Get the JSON representation of a model and an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A **QuestionTag** belongs_to a **Tag**.

I want to get the JSON representation of a **QuestionTag**, and some information from the **Tag** it belongs to.  What is the correct Rails-Activerecord query to get me this structure from a controller action?

```
{
  question_id: 1,
  name: "PHP",
  description: "A programming language for monkeys."
}
```

Here are the tables:

```
QuestionTag
  question_id
  tag_id

Tag
  name
  description
```

Comment: It depends on how you build your json

Comment: It also depends on where you want to use it. View? Controller? Model? Service?

Comment: Ah sorry, I would like to render the JSON in a controller (API response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you controller, when you send back the response in JSON format, you can do something like following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render :json => @tag.to_json(:include => { :question_tag => { :only => :question_id } })
  end
end
```

Now, it will send response in the following format. It will send only `question_id` form `QuestionTag` table.

```
{
  name: "name",
  description: "description",
  question_id: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arslan - so that will return the QuestionTag nested in the Tag.  I'm actually trying to make a particular JSON form where it is only one level deep.

Comment: Please post what kind of JSON actually you want to get back? Like what you have posted in your question?